# How can I use formcontrol in markdown

Tags: angular, typescript, markdown, angular-reactive-forms

In markdown, I replace the some of text with textbox and added formcontrol but I don't get the value of this input. Input is avilable in UI but how can I get formcontrol value? I am using ngx-markdown.

Here code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXz0V.png)

Html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="markdownForm">
    <markdown [data]="mdData"></markdown>
</form>
```

ts code:

```
export class MarkDownComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public mdData: any;
  markdownForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private markdownService: MarkdownService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.markdownForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: new FormControl(''),
    });
    this.mdData = this.mdData.replace(
      /@\TextBox\b\((.*?)\)/g,
      "<inject key='$1' value='$1' name='textbox'></inject>"
    );
    this.markdownService.renderer.html = (inject: string) => {
      if (inject === '</inject>') {
        return '';
      }
      const elm = stringToHtml(inject);
      if (elm) {
        const name = elm.getAttribute('name');
        const value = elm.getAttribute('value');
        if (name === 'textbox') {
          return this.setTextboxHTML(
            '',
            value,
            value.replace(/ +/g, '').toLowerCase()
          );
        }
      }
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
      return '';
    };
  }
  setTextboxHTML(props, value, label) {
    this.markdownForm.addControl(label, new FormControl(''));
    return <input type='text' formControlName='${label}' name='${label}' />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Code is a text, why would you make image of a text instead of putting text here?

Comment: Sorry for that but I tried to fix  'stack overflow error Please indent all code by 4 spaces using...' error and It's taking too much time So I add image.
Code added now

Comment: You could just mark the code and click "code" button in the editor, so no indentation needed.